# How to get start, schedule and finish timestamp when submitting a callable/runnable task with Hazelcast DurableExecutorService?

Tags: hazelcast

Below is the basic example of submitting a callable/runable to executor service:

```html
// Executor: instance of Hazelcast's durable executor service
// Task: a simple callable

future = executor.submit(task);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way in the API.

With a normal Java runnable/callable (no Hazelcast) there isn't really a way either.

You can obviously capture the timestamp in your code just before the submit and after the future is available.

In a callable, at the start and end of the `run()` method you could capture the timestamps, and somehow include that in the result returned.

Not really an elegant answer!